# comparar tamanho do pdf em laravel

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

Seguinte tenho uma aplicação em laravel que eu coloco um pdf em um cadastro, mas quando o pdf é muito grande ele da erro, teria como eu saber até qual tamanho de pdf eu posso usar e se o cara colocar um pdf maior que o limite eu mostrar uma mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber o tamanho do arquivo usando Laravel a partir da versão 5.7 você pode usar o método `getSize()`. Em versões anteriores, o método é `getClientSize()`. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

**Laravel < 5.7**

```
$request->file('file')->getClientSize();
```

**Laravel >= 5.7**

```
$request->file('file')->getSize();
```

Veja [esta documentação](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-4.1.md#httpfoundation) para mais detalhes.

Aqui está outro exemplo de como usar a função `filesize()` em Laravel para comparar o tamanho de dois arquivos PDF:

```
$file1 = 'caminho/do/arquivo1.pdf';
$file2 = 'caminho/do/arquivo2.pdf';

if (filesize($file1) > filesize($file2)) {
    // arquivo1.pdf é maior que arquivo2.pdf
} elseif (filesize($file1) < filesize($file2)) {
    // arquivo2.pdf é maior que arquivo1.pdf
} else {
    // ambos os arquivos têm o mesmo tamanho
}
```